Python sockio SimpleClient fails to connect to python-socketio
I've got a python backend with python-socketio as server. I have a react application which can connect to it just fine. However, my python client app always raises a 'connectionError'.
I need some help to get the settings correct.
Python client
socket_client.connect(
        'wss://SERVER:9001',
        namespace='/cli',
        socketio_path='socket',
        transports=['websocket']
    )

React client
const manager = new Manager(
            'wss://SERVER:9001',
            {
                path: '/socket,
                transports: ['websocket'],
                rejectUnauthorized: false,
                autoConnect: true
            }
        );
this.manager.socket('/cli').connect()

The python backend is fastapi with socketio and currently has cors allowed origins to everything (just trying to connect). The mode is asgi
The last error lines from the client when trying to connect
  File "D:\Projects\FOLDER\.venv\Lib\site-packages\socketio\client.py", line 159, in connect
    raise exceptions.ConnectionError(exc.args[0]) from None
socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError: Connection error

Both client and server are running version 5.11.4.
Edit: Change protocol
If I switch to https and polling I get this message
socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='SERVER', port=9001): Max retries exceeded with url: /socket/?transport=polling&EIO=4&t=1730702846.0515244 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1020)')))

The react is https, the fastapi app also runs https. Both use the same certificate files (a wildcard not self made)

I figured it out. The client needs the certificate as well. Searching around I found the solution here
So I switched to AsyncClient (I'll use that anyway). This meant moving the connection to a async function so the connection is done with a await. Then, as per the description of the github discussion

create a default context
load the cert chain
create a connector
create a clientsession
load the clientsession to the AsyncClient

Very 'top level' code snippet
    ctx = create_default_context(Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
    ctx.load_cert_chain('certs/FILE.crt', 'certs/FILE.key')
    conn = TCPConnector(ssl_context=ctx)
    cs = ClientSession(connector=conn)

    socket_client = AsyncClient(http_session=cs, ssl_verify=False, logger=True, engineio_logger=True)

    await socket_client.connect(
        'wss://SERVER:9001',
        namespaces='/cli',
        socketio_path='socket',
        transports=['websocket']
    )

